# Ругается на мою функцию "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare previously declared in"

Tags: php

Выдаётся ошибка на мою функцию:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare mqfa1() (previously declared in
>   Y:\home\bkwar.r\www\connect.php:48) in Y:\home\bkwar.r\www\connect.php
>   on line 52

*Вот часть кода на из-за которого вся проблема*

```
 function mqfa1($sql, $pos=0){
   if (strpos($sql,"show fields")===false && strpos($sql," limit ")===false) 
     $sql.=" limit 1";
   $a=mysql_fetch_row(mq("$sql"));
   return $a[$pos];
 }

 function mqfa($sql){
   if (strpos($sql,"show fields")===false && strpos($sql," limit ")===false) 
     $sql.=" limit 1";
   $a=mysql_fetch_assoc(mq("$sql"));
   return $a;
 }

 function mqfaa($sql){
   //if (strpos($sql,"show fields")===false && strpos($sql," limit ")===false) $sql.=" limit 1";
   $a=mq("$sql");
   $res = array();
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($a)) {
     $res[] = $row;
   }
 }
```

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: ошибка о том, что в строке 52 объявлятся функция mqfa1 которая уже объявлена в строке 48, в php так нельзя.

Comment: если ее убрать на линии 52, то ругается все равно

Comment: так же точно ? вы хотя-бы google translate используйте для перевода ошибок.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in

Говорит что неожиданное завершение

Comment: не закрыта скобка... давайте вы как нибудь сами синтаксис выучите ?

Comment: капец, вы у меня спросили как ругается, я вам сказал. то что скобка не закрыта я догадался

Comment: Вы отредактируйте вопрос - подправьте скобку и т.п. Потому что сейчас в mqfaa скобка не закрыта и не понятно, какую вообще проблему решаем. И строка 52 это первая в Вашем листинге? А с 48 по 52 что?

Answer (score 1):

Это значит, что функция mqfa1() уже была определена в файле Y:\home\bkwar.r\www\connect.php